# use maven modules to build springmvc framework,but I can't find controller

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I'm new to use maven module,and I want to build a simple web project using springMVC.

the framework is simple,I have "config","api", and "parent" projects.the "parent" project is the parent of the other two modules.the "api" module depends on "config" module.

the pom of parent project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>website</id>
            <url>scp://webhost.company.com/www/website</url>
        </site>
    </distributionManagement>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <modules>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>config</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web Container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and the pom of config module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>config Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>config</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the pom of api module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>api Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>api</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the outline of the two projects:

[the api module just has a controller in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAK0Z.png)

[the frame work of config module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuEYE.png)

the code in config project are simple codes to start spring-mvc.
I'm just showwing the key code.

the code of AppBoot.java:

```
package api;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppBoot extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { App.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

}
```

the code of the webConfig.java:

```
package api;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "api")
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext arg0) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
        super.configureDefaultServletHandling(configurer);
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

the code of "TestApiController"  and "TestApi" are same:

```
@RestController
public class TestApiController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String test() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

when I call "TestApiController" in config module,it works well,but when I call the  TestApi controller in api module,it shows 404.

I guess,because the "api" depends on "config",so the packages in "api"are not visible to "config",and the annotation @ComponentScan can't scan the packages in "api" module,so the controller didn't inject in context.I don't know if my guess is right and I don't know how to fix it either.

Comment: show more details ..

Comment: I've added the details,thanks